# How do you specify which XmlPackage to use in aspdotnetstorefront v10

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I haven't used aspdotnetstorefront in some time. I'm upgrade a v9.3 site to v10.0. It seems the XmlPackage that was written for a series of products no longer works and I just want to use one of the very simple out-of-the-box XmlPackages. In the admin site, there doesn't seem to be any way to specify which XmlPackage. So I changed it in the database. I reset the cache, reset IIS, etc., all to no avail. It just wants to use the old package.

Looking for some help!

Answer (score 1):

The product manager still has the ability to change an xmlpackage. The drop down now displays a configurable display name instead of the xmlpackage file name in version 10 out of the box. The admin overhaul could be making it so you are not used to where editors are also. For editing products use the left hand navigation and the go to Products -> Product Manager.

Editing form the database should still work also however. Make sure the file names and product ids match exactly when updating the database directly.

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are seeing. When I go to Products | Manage Products (I don't see "Product Manager") and I select a product, there are dropdowns for Product Type, Manufacturer, Distributor, Page Display, Tax Class, and Quantity Discount Table.  The Page Display drop down shows 7 items starting with "Simple Product" and ending with Variants in "Dropdown with Tabbed Layout."  I don't see any way to edit this value, I can only select what is there.  This is under the Main Tab.

Comment: OK - discovered my packages were under the root XmlPackages folder but not under the skin I was using, which they apparently must be to be picked up and added to the dropdown.